# How do we lookup all image tags in a repo with the same sha?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration

So I'm currently working on hacking together Baby's first deployment pipeline for my current company.

What I'd really like to do is have an image corp/app:sha-SOME_SHA, push it to staging, run all the unit tests, then push a tag corp/app:staging-validated.  Which is trivial and we're already doing this.

And then the bit I don't see a good way of doing is to go:

1. Look up corp/app:staging-validated for the image sha
2. Look up all the other tags on that Docker sha for the one matching sha-LONG_HEX
3. Push that sha-LONG_HEX tag to prod

Is there an easy way to find "All tags that share with a Dockerhub tag" in a repo?

Comment: Will this help you? This will print out SHAs that are duplicates on your local registry

`docker image ls -q | xargs -I {} docker inspect {} -f '{{.Id}}' | sort | uniq -cd`